# Add descriptions for each comment flag option into the flag dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-flags

When flagging a comment the following dialog is displayed:

[image: Older version of the comment flag dialog. Title: “I am flagging this comment as …”. Five radio button options. First: “rude or offensive”. Second: “not constructive”. Third: “obsolete”. Fourth: “too chatty”. Fifth: “other…”.]

For people who have little or no experience in flagging, I think it would be beneficial to add the text from the [Flagging a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) section of the Help Center and bring this dialog in line with other flagging dialogs.

For example, the following text is given for the “not constructive” flag:

> A comment that does not try to improve the post it appears on, or which introduces a topic unrelated to the question or answer.

In the dialog pictured above, there is no tool-tip or link to this information anywhere.

This is my suggestion for the comment flagging dialog:

[image: A comment flag dialog with texts from the help center explaining each flag option, beneath the radio button labels.]

To be clear, I’m not suggesting that comments are in any way more important, that we should protect them or treat them any differently.

I understand comments are second-class citizens and I agree with this. I was thinking that this feature request would improve consistency between the rest of the dialogs and show the flag description.

Comment: Make that *22 flags remaining* in red. :-)

Comment: I thought I knew the difference between "not constructive" (which I took to mean "argumentative") and "too chatty" ("irrelevant", like thank-yous and please-look-at-my-other-questions), but with those descriptions I can't tell.  I know it doesn't really matter what I pick (other than rude/abusive), but I actually think that text is more likely to confuse than help.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Those are just the descriptions I pulled from the help center.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I know, and I wasn't blaming you, just pointing out to the devs that they might want to rework that text if they implement this request.

Comment: This FR appears to attempt making comment flagging a more scrutinized process in order to protect comments. Stop obsessing over comments.

Comment: No, I could care less about the comments, this is about putting the flag description in the dialog, like the rest of flagging dialogs.  :-)

Comment: I'd suggest that make little different between *posts flag dialog* and the *comments flag dialog*...not only make that *22 flags remaining* in red as @BhargavRao suggested :)

Comment: Looks like this has been [meta-tag:status-completed] for a long time now.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Then *raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag* to request that the [meta-tag:status-completed] be added. Adding a comment that it should happen doesn't, necessarily, bring it to the attention of moderators, who are the ones with the ability to add that tag.